# why my normals are inverted in the other side?

Tags: normal-map

Hello i have my model that is done, so i have overlaped the faces that are simetricall such as the skirt, torso and face. And the ones i have made the normal map details have been distorted in this way.

[image: This is my model, the goal is to achieve the left side in the right side.]

The mirror modifier was already apllied in this model, but my question is why if the same mesh shares same uv of the normal looks like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "so i have overlaped the faces that ..."? overlapped = mirrored? Does the image show the low-poly mesh with the normal map applied? Have you set the Colorspace of the Image Texture of the normal map to Non-Color?

Comment: i have my mirror uv so i can use the same side of the mesh that is the same like the skirt by example.So skirt circle is overlaped the half side to share the same info of the normal, and it is in non color. But it gives me this result. I dont know what to do,i even flipped the faces of the left side to se the result but it is not.